# IEnumerable query with GroupBy with Min and Projection

Tags: linq, data-structures, linq-to-objects

I have these arrays correlated by index. So for each index (ObjId, ObjState) form a pair.

```
 string[] ObjIds = { "Obj1", "Obj1", "Obj2", "Obj2", "Obj1", "Obj3", "Obj2", "Obj2" };
 string[] ObjStates = { "OS11", "OS12", "OS21", "OS22", "OS13", "OS31", "OS22", "OS23" };
```

However I only want the most recent pair (closest to index 0) for each ObjId.

For the above input, the output would be

```
{  Obj1, OS11 }, {Obj2, OS21}, {Obj3, OS31}
```

How do I do this using an IEnumerable query? I'm having trouble with figuring out how to keep track of the index.

Comment: What have you tried? And what is the rule of grouping? Why there are three objects in result? Why `{Obj2, OS23}` is not in results?

Comment: I think you've entirely misinterpreted this situation. To indulge you, there are three objects in the results because I defined the problem. {Obj2, OS23} is not in the results for the same reason.

Comment: I didn't misinterpret anything. I just asked questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
var items = ObjIds.Zip(ObjStates, (id, st) => new {Id = id, State = st})
                  .GroupBy(i => i.Id)
                  .Select(g => g.First());
```

`Enumerable.Zip` is used here "pair up" the items for you into a new anonymous type, and then the items are grouped, and the first item is selected from each group.